# How to pivot two columns at a time?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Consider this input and I wish to pivot `val1` and `val2` using `cname` as column name.

```
wide = DataFrame(x = 1:12,
       a  = 2:13,
       b  = 3:14,
       val1  = randn(12),
       val2  = randn(12),
       cname = repeat(["c", "d"], inner =6)
       )

12×6 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ a     │ b     │ val1      │ val2      │ cname  │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Float64   │ Float64   │ String │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │ 1.51014   │ -1.18548  │ c      │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 3     │ 4     │ 0.0845411 │ -0.370083 │ c      │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 4     │ 5     │ 0.826283  │ -1.00423  │ c      │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │ -0.53175  │ -1.16659  │ c      │
│ 5   │ 5     │ 6     │ 7     │ -1.77975  │ 0.336333  │ c      │
│ 6   │ 6     │ 7     │ 8     │ 0.632577  │ 0.236621  │ c      │
│ 7   │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │ -0.681532 │ 1.14869   │ d      │
│ 8   │ 8     │ 9     │ 10    │ -0.775619 │ 0.393475  │ d      │
│ 9   │ 9     │ 10    │ 11    │ -0.533034 │ 0.059624  │ d      │
│ 10  │ 10    │ 11    │ 12    │ 0.496152  │ -1.23507  │ d      │
│ 11  │ 11    │ 12    │ 13    │ 0.834099  │ 2.12115   │ d      │
│ 12  │ 12    │ 13    │ 14    │ 0.532357  │ -0.369267 │ d      │
```

In the tidyverse, the `pivot_wider` function can do this

```
wide %>% pivot_wider(names_from = cname, values_from = c(val1,val2))


===  ===  ===  ==========  ==========  ==========  ==========
  x    a    b      val1_c      val1_d      val2_c      val2_d
===  ===  ===  ==========  ==========  ==========  ==========
  1    2    3   1.0174232          NA  -0.6611959          NA
  2    3    4   0.6590795          NA  -2.0954505          NA
  3    4    5   1.2939581          NA   1.6350356          NA
  4    5    6  -1.9395356          NA   0.7813238          NA
  5    6    7   0.3558087          NA   0.9789414          NA
  6    7    8   0.9859100          NA  -0.9803336          NA
  7    8    9          NA   0.4949224          NA  -0.0659333
  8    9   10          NA   0.5024755          NA  -0.2317832
  9   10   11          NA   1.6926897          NA  -0.3840687
 10   11   12          NA  -0.4324705          NA  -0.0901276
 11   12   13          NA  -0.6415260          NA   0.0014151
 12   13   14          NA   1.2406868          NA  -2.1959740
===  ===  ===  ==========  ==========  ==========  ==========
```

Julia's `DataFrames.unstack` does not work

For example

```
using DataFrames
unstack(wide, [:x, :a,:b], :cname, [:val1,:val2])
```

What is the R (data.table)/Scala/etc solution for comparison? Solutions from any language welcome.

But I don't want any python solutions as it clashes with another.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this currently is not supported in DataFrames.jl in one call (but the feature was requested to be added to `unstack`, so it will be available in the future). Currently you have to do:

```
tmp = [unstack(wide, [:x, :a, :b], :cname, v, renamecols=x->v*"_"*x) for v in ["val1", "val2"]]
result = [tmp[1] tmp[2][:, 4:end]]
```

or

```
innerjoin([unstack(wide, [:x, :a, :b], :cname, v, renamecols=x->v*"_"*x) for v in ["val1", "val2"]]..., on=[:x, :a, :b])
```